# adding a column with numbered observations per id

Tags: data

Good day I have a dataset that is in long form with sheep IDs and their lamb IDs.
There are multiple rows per ewe as they have multiple lambs each with a unique id.
I don't want a count per ewe, but wanted to somehow add a column that lists the lambs 1, 2, 3...for each ewe so I can then use that variable to throw the data wide. Any thoughts? I have included an example and am most familiar with R.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this and am not sure where my code is going awry...births is the dataset name:

```
for(i in 2:nrow(births)) {       
    births$num_lambs[i, ] <- ifelse(births$Dam_last9[i, ]==births$Dam_last9[(i-1), ], births$num_lambs[i-1,]+1, 1)
}
```